# Installing git on Windows: Git Bash Here or git-cheetah shell extension?

Tags: git, installation

I'm installing Git on Windows XP. During the setup, the installer asks whether I want:

> 1: Context menu entries: "Git Bash Here" (and the "Git GUI Here" option)

or

> 2: "git-cheetah shell extension (32-bit only)"

Basically, which should I do? I can't do both.

More specifically, what is the most commonly used version? Is the Git Bash tool the same as the shell extension?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`git bash here` will give you a console window with access to git commands, `shell extension` will give you right click menu access to git commands creating an environment similar to `TortoiseSVN` and such.

Comment: Despite the installer choices suggesting you can't do both, selecting git-cheetah does give you git bash + git gui as well.